# jQuery - create element on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create simple color picker, where I create picker in function.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpbdj4Lm/

**Problem:**

I want to create element with colors (`<div class="picker">`) **inside** function , so that HTML markup is not in page, but it will be created when button is clicked.

so html markup will be only link.

**Wanted result:**

[image: todo.png]

**Scenario:**

When I click on button ( icon ) then hover DIV will appear where I choose color by clicking on it. When I click on color, picker will hide.

**My work so far:**

```js
$('.button').click(function (event) {

    // create picker ( create DIV element )
  
    //$('.picker').toggleClass('open');
    

});

$('.color').click(function (event) {

    var chosen_color = $(this).css('backgound-color');
    console.log(chosen_color);
  
  
    // hide picker
    //$('.picker').removeClass('open');
  

});
```

```css
.button {
        
}

.picker {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 70px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}

.color {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 2px 1px 1px 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}

#blue {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/color_swatch.png" />
</a>

<div class="picker">
    <div class="color" id="red"></div>
    <div class="color" id="green"></div>
    <div class="color" id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's absolutely no advantage to add the markup dynamically they way it's made in the selected answer. Having static markup is much better for readability if you aren't planning to make something more modular or flexible like I showed in my answer.

Comment: @plax appriciate suggestion, I took some ideas to use. I agree with that static html markup is better, but in case of usage I need to avoid that. Thanks for excelent response, I added ratting to answer as it should be marked as answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle precisely as you want,

```
http://jsfiddle.net/cpbdj4Lm/48/
```

Basically the idea is to keep HTML string in code. Once there is a click on .picker, just append it to DOM.

```
    var pickerHTMLString = '<div class="picker"><div class="color" id="red"></div><div class="color" id="green"></div><div class="color" id="blue"></div></div>';
    var pickerDOMElements = $.parseHTML(pickerHTMLString);

    $('.button').click(function (event) {
        if ($('.picker').length === 0) {
            $('body').append(pickerDOMElements);
            // Attach click handler on .color only once it is attached to DOM
            $('.color').click(function (event) {
                var chosen_color = $(this).css('backgound-color');
                $('.picker').remove();
                console.log(chosen_color);
            });
        } else {
            $('.picker').remove();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply a syntax error as far as I can tell...

`$.('.picker').toggleClass('open');` should be `$('.picker').toggleClass('open');`

Works as expected that way.

EDIT:

Sorry I misunderstood your question. Well, to make your code more modular you could write a little plugin that encapsulates the color picker logic, including the rendering. The way I designed it is that the picker's markup will only be added to the DOM the first time the plugin is clicked.

Here's an exemple:

Using the plugin:

```
var pickerColors = ['red', 'yellow', '#00ffff', 'blue', 'brown', 'orange'];

$('img').colorPicker({ colors: pickerColors }).on({
    'beforeshow.colorpicker': function () { console.log('before show'); },
    'beforecolorselect.colorpicker': function (e) {
        if (e.color == 'blue') {
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent color selection
            alert(e.color + ' cannot be selected');
        }
    },
    'colorselect.colorpicker': function (e) {
        console.log('color selected', e.color);
    }
});
```

The full sample:

```js
//Sample plugin that encapsulates the color picker logic

!function ($, doc) {
    
    var defaults;
    
    function ColorPicker($el, config) {
        this._$picker = null;
        this._$el = $el;
        this._config = config;
        this._selectedColor = null;
        
        togglePickerOnElClick.call(this);
    }
    ColorPicker.prototype = {
        constructor: ColorPicker,
        
        show: function () { 
            pickerEl.call(this).show(); 
            anchorPickerToEl.call(this);
        },
        hide: function () { pickerEl.call(this).hide(); },
        toggleDisplay: function () {
            var $picker = pickerEl.call(this);
            this[$picker.is(':visible')? 'hide' : 'show']();
        },
        get selectedColor() { return this._selectedColor; }
    };
        
    function anchorPickerToEl() {
        var $el = this._$el,
            elOffset = $el.offset();
        
        this._$picker.offset({
            top: elOffset.top + $el.outerHeight(),
            left: elOffset.left
        });
    }
    
    function onColorSelected(e) {
        var evtData = { color: $(e.target).attr('data-color') };
    
        if (trigger.call(this, 'beforecolorselect.colorpicker', evtData)) {
            this.hide();
            
            this._selectedColor = evtData.color;
            
            trigger.call(this, 'colorselect.colorpicker', evtData);
        }
    }
    
    function togglePickerOnElClick() {
        var that = this;
        
        this._$el.click(function () {
            if (trigger.call(that, 'beforeshow.colorpicker')) {
                that.toggleDisplay();
            }
        });
    }
        
    function initPickerBehaviors() {
        this._$picker.on('click', '.color-picker-color', $.proxy(onColorSelected, this));
    }
    
    function trigger(eventName, data) {
        var evt = $.Event(eventName);
        
        $.extend(evt, data);
            
        this._$el.trigger(evt);
        
        return !evt.isDefaultPrevented();
    }
    
    function pickerEl() {
        if (!this._$picker) {
            var config = this._config;
            
            this._$picker = $('<ul class="color-picker"></ul>')
                .hide() //fixes :isvisible bug when not in DOM
                .append(config.colors.map(
                   function (color) {
                        return $('<li class="color-picker-color"></li>')
                            .css('background-color', color)
                            .attr('data-color', color);
                    }
                )).appendTo(doc.body);
            
            initPickerBehaviors.call(this);
        }
            
        return this._$picker;
    }
               
    function applyDefaults(config) {
        return $.extend(defaults, config || {});
    }
    
    function applyPluginIfNotAlreadyApplied($el, config) {
        var instance = $el.data('colorPicker');
        
        if (!instance) $el.data('colorPicker', new ColorPicker($el, config));
    }
    
    $.fn.extend({ 
        colorPicker: function (config) {
            config = applyDefaults(config);
            
            return this.each(function () {
               applyPluginIfNotAlreadyApplied($(this), config);
            });
        }
    });
    
    defaults = $.fn.colorPicker.defaults = {
        colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    };
}(jQuery, document);


//Using the plugin

var pickerColors = ['red', 'yellow', '#00ffff', 'blue', 'brown', 'orange'];

var picker = $('img').colorPicker({ colors: pickerColors }).on({
    'beforeshow.colorpicker': function () { console.log('before show'); },
    'beforecolorselect.colorpicker': function (e) {
        if (e.color == 'blue') {
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent color selection
            alert(e.color + ' cannot be selected');
        }
    },
    'colorselect.colorpicker': function (e) {
        console.log('color selected', e.color);
    }
}).data('colorPicker');

//Show or hide picker programmatically
$('button').click(function (e) {
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');

    if (action == 'alertColor') {
        alert(picker.selectedColor);
        return;
    }

    picker[action]();
});
```

```css
img {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.color-picker {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    max-width: 120px;
}

.color-picker-color {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/color_swatch.png" />

<div class="buttons">
    <button data-action="show">Show</button>
    <button data-action="hide">Hide</button>
    <button data-action="toggleDisplay">Toggle</button>
    <button data-action="alertColor">Alert selected color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: question is, how to create <div class="picker"> inside function ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to make that div appear once the button is clicked, you could do that with css (add/remove a css class like 'hide' that sets 'display: none').

If for some reason you want to physically add the element to the DOM inside that function, then you can use jQuery's 'append' method (`$('whatever').append('<div></div>')`.  It's a little nasty, as you have to build up the whole div using strings.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rcyxccuf/

(this fiddle inserts the html you have above correctly, though nothing is visible as you currently have it, because it is all empty divs)

Comment: how to append only once ? Limit it by some counter ?

Comment: It is sounding more and more like you can just get what you want using CSS.  Just toggle the visibility of a div that is already in the DOM.  If you absolutely, positively can't have the html in the DOM for some reason, then yeah either set a flag or better yet, use jQuery to look for the '.picker' and only append if it isn't there.